# Meaning of fields in "Enable Wi-Fi verbose logging"

Tags: wi-fi, logging, developer-options

Does anyone have a link to clear docs on the meaning of all the fields for Wi-Fi networks when I **Enable Wi-Fi verbose logging** in the developer options?

I can guess a few and worst case I can read the source, but I was hoping for a clear and simple table.

Specific fields are:

- rssi (this is about the only one I'm 100% clear on)
- score
- tx
- rx

Also, the extra data after the mac address of each access point, e.g.

```
[(1){FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF*=2462,-49,4s};]
```

Comment: tx/rx is send/receive (Transmit/Receive). No idea what is scored there, though, or by what criteria.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed tx/rx are related to send/receive, but I've no idea what the units are

Comment: Me neither, never enabled that. Maybe someone else can bring in the next piece …

Answer (score 0):

The data after: the first number should be frequency (Mhz) and signal strength (dB) of the connection. Don't know about last one, but (n)s is standard notation for (n)seconds... Perhaps the log interval.